# pip install simple-crypt - failing in rhel7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I want to install `simple-crypt` package in python2.7 virtual env but it's failing with below errors:

```
   # pip list
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
    Package      Version
    ------------ -------
    pip          20.0.2
    pycryptodome 3.9.7
    setuptools   44.0.0
    wheel        0.34.2

    # python --version
    Python 2.7.5

    # pip install simple-crypt
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
    Processing /root/.cache/pip/wheels/da/18/8d/5b0bc872d10ac287c46543e49480ec771b3d6b69fb9e483364/simple_crypt-4.1.7-py2-none-any.whl
    Collecting pycrypto
      Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
      Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /home/user1/Environments/tac_bck_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-SlQ08b
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/
      Complete output (213 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
      copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
      copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/hashalgo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Cipher
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/RFC1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/py21compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/randpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/py3compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/Util/number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Util
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/Fortuna
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/rng_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Random/OSRNG
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/st_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_importKey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_rpoolcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_generic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
      copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
      copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
      running build_ext
      running build_configure
      checking for gcc... gcc
      checking whether the C compiler works... yes
      checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
      checking for suffix of executables...
      checking whether we are cross compiling... no
      checking for suffix of object files... o
      checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
      checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
      checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
      checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
      checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... no
      checking whether mpz_powm is declared... no
      checking whether mpz_powm_sec is declared... no
      checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
      checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
      checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
      checking for ANSI C header files... yes
      checking for sys/types.h... yes
      checking for sys/stat.h... yes
      checking for stdlib.h... yes
      checking for string.h... yes
      checking for memory.h... yes
      checking for strings.h... yes
      checking for inttypes.h... yes
      checking for stdint.h... yes
      checking for unistd.h... yes
      checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
      checking limits.h usability... yes
      checking limits.h presence... yes
      checking for limits.h... yes
      checking stddef.h usability... yes
      checking stddef.h presence... yes
      checking for stddef.h... yes
      checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
      checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
      checking for string.h... (cached) yes
      checking wchar.h usability... yes
      checking wchar.h presence... yes
      checking for wchar.h... yes
      checking for inline... inline
      checking for int16_t... yes
      checking for int32_t... yes
      checking for int64_t... yes
      checking for int8_t... yes
      checking for size_t... yes
      checking for uint16_t... yes
      checking for uint32_t... yes
      checking for uint64_t... yes
      checking for uint8_t... yes
      checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
      checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
      checking for memmove... yes
      checking for memset... yes
      configure: creating ./config.status
      config.status: creating src/config.h
      warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
      building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
      gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/home/user1/Environments/tac_bck_env/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
      src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include "Python.h"
                          ^
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
      Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
    Failed to build pycrypto
    Installing collected packages: pycrypto, simple-crypt
        Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /home/user1/Environments/tac_bck_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ML3YHN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user1/Environments/tac_bck_env/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto
             cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/
        Complete output (158 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
        copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
        copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
        copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash
        copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Hash

        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher`enter code here`
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_XOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash

        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_importKey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_rpoolcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna/test_SHAd256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/Fortuna
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_generic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_nt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_fallback.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/OSRNG
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_winrandom.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/Chaffing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
        copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/AllOrNothing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Protocol
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/_slowmath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
        copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature
        running build_ext
        running build_configure
        warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
        building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
        gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/home/xyz/Environments/tac_bck_env/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
        src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
         #include "Python.h"
                            ^
        compilation terminated.
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/xyz/Environments/tac_bck_env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xAgvDW/pycrypto/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ML3YHN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/xyz
    /Environments/tac_bck_env/include/site/python2.7/pycrypto Check the logs for full command output.
```

Installed all dependencies but still it's failing, Please guide me if missing here anything..thanks

Comment: Don't know if this the cause for your issue, but as the message itself states right there in the top, Python 2 is not supported by pip and you should upgrade to a newer version (current latest is 3.8)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 1):

You do need to install the Python2 C headers.
For instance, in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

Comment: The OP asked about RedHat. Not `apt-get` but `yum` and package names must be different.

Comment: @phd where does it sat "RedHat"?

Comment: **rhel7** in the title = RedHat Enterprise Linux version 7.